# Race Condition Google SpreadSheets API v4 on Java

Tags: java, api, spreadsheet, race-condition

I developed an application on Java using Google SpreadSheets API v4. I write data obtained from the users into the SpreadSheet. To get the last row written (in order to write in a new cell) I use this code.

```
public static String lastRow(String page, String column) throws IOException {
    Sheets sheetsService = getSheetsService();
    String range = page+ "!" + column + "2:" + column + "100000";

    ValueRange result = sheetsService.spreadsheets().values().get(SPREADSHEET_ID, range).execute();
    int numRows = result.getValues() != null ? result.getValues().size() : 0;

    return page + "!" + column + (numRows + 2);
}
```

That returns a `String` that shows where I have to write a new value.

The Race Condition starts when two users get the same `lastRow` to write, and they overwrite each other. There is something I can do to solve it? For example, if someone writes on the SpreadSheet, block the entire page, or something like that, or maybe creating a priority list, but I didn't come up to a valid solution.

Comment: First of all the method must be synchronized. The would avoid any kind of race condition. In the second instance, you must clarify the program behavior, should your code reject always the oldest one? synchronized instruction would be enough. In other cases, you may want to create a priority list to file manipulation (owner/editor /etc), but it's up to you and you shold specify in your question

Comment: @Thecave3 Adding `synchronized` to the method, won't solve anything because I don't have access to the Google Server. It would keep overwriting if the race condition happens.

Comment: Is this client code? You should have pointed out. I thought this was a middleware/server code. So i'm asking you what is the expected behaviour of your code?

Comment: You may consider creating copies of your document, making the user writing on them and finally merge all with your logic

Comment: @TheCave3 Yes it is client code, sorry I didn't mention before